# what does "同士な" mean in this sentence

Tags: words

I want to translate this sentence 
"ウチらの好きな男子同士なんだからさ!",but i don't understand "同士な"'s mean
Help me

Comment: ～同士 is a noun which is also called a "no-adjective". It can take な in various situations, especially before "explanatory の". Please read the linked article.